# How can I filter by date, time and second in django?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

In my Database I have lots of entries with various Dates(including time, second). I need to find all the latest entries.

So I tried like:

```
    arr = balance_sheet.objects.all().values('timestump')
    date_arr=[]
    for text in arr:
        if text.get('timestump'):
            date_arr.append(text.get('timestump'))
    if date_arr:
        latest_date = max(date_arr)
    else:
        latest_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    latest = balance_sheet.objects.filter(timestump__icontains=latest_date)
```

But `latest` is empty in this case.
But If I change the last line to query with only the date, it works fine, but returns all the entries of the day.

```
latest = balance_sheet.objects.filter(timestump__icontains=latest_date.date())
```

I need to find all the latest minute:second entries. At latest last minute in entries.

I get:

```
2020-07-05 12:54:35.656849
2020-07-05 12:54:35.844049
2020-07-05 12:54:36.015650
2020-07-05 12:54:36.156050
2020-07-05 12:55:04.314099
2020-07-05 12:55:04.454500
2020-07-05 12:55:04.579300
2020-07-05 12:55:04.735300
```

Am I doing something wrong?

How can I get all the same minute entries only? As:

```
2020-07-05 12:55:04.314099
2020-07-05 12:55:04.454500
2020-07-05 12:55:04.579300
2020-07-05 12:55:04.735300
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return the latest object by time? **`balance_sheet.objects.order_by('-timestump').first()`** ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes It does. Thank you. I still want to learn about the fact I asked. For larger database ordering may slow down the program.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu But it returns just one last value. I have multiple values as last entry.

Comment: @RafiSarker: no, manually determining the maximum based on all records will be a *lot* slower, since it requires more bandwidth, does processing at the Python/Django layer, requires two roundtrips to the database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A database can return the latest record itself. You can for example make use of [**`.latest(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
latest_sheet = balance_sheet.objects.latest('timestump')
```

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_name.balance_sheet
ORDER BY timestump DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will limit the bandwidth significantly, and furthermore databases are optimized to perform such queries.

We can however first fetch the largest minute:

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMinute

latest_minute = balance_sheet.objects.aggregate(mx=Max(ExtractMinute('timestump'))['mx']
latest_sheets = balance_sheet.objects.annotate(
    mn=ExtractMinute('timestump')
).filter(mn=last_minute)
```

or if it is for the latest truncated minute:

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMinute

latest_minute = balance_sheet.objects.aggregate(mx=Max(TruncMinute('timestump'))['mx']
latest_sheets = balance_sheet.objects.annotate(
    mn=TruncMinute('timestump')
).filter(mn=last_minute)
```

What might help is add a database index on the `balance_sheet` model:

```
class balance_sheet(models.Model):
    # …
    timestump = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `BalanceSheet` instead of <s>`balance_sheet`</s>.

Comment: Using `latest` neither solves the problem. Consider Some entry like:
`2020-07-05 12:54:35.656849
2020-07-05 12:54:35.844049
2020-07-05 12:54:36.015650
2020-07-05 12:54:36.156050
2020-07-05 12:55:04.314099
2020-07-05 12:55:04.454500
2020-07-05 12:55:04.579300
2020-07-05 12:55:04.735300`

Here all the dates are same, but if we consider minutes there are two group of entries. I need the latest group.

Comment: @RafiSarker: well what does it return, and what is the expected result?

Comment: @RafiSarker: if I try this locally, it returns the object with `timestump = 2020-07-05 12:55:04.735300`.

Comment: But I need, to get:
`2020-07-05 12:55:04.314099
2020-07-05 12:55:04.454500
2020-07-05 12:55:04.579300
2020-07-05 12:55:04.735300`

Because, these all entries at 12:55:04 were done at once through a loop.

Comment: In case of:

`latest = balance_sheet.objects.filter(timestump__icontains=latest_date)`

I get:

`[]` (empty query)

In case of:

`latest = balance_sheet.objects.filter(timestump__icontains=latest_date.date())`

I get:

`2020-07-05 12:55:04.735300` (which is not also expected)

Comment: @RafiSarker: see edit, this will return all the records with the maximum number of minutes.

Comment: Edited the question.

requirement is: latest date, latest hour of the date, latest minute of the our. But there may be multiple entries of belongs to those conditions. The methods you explained in the answers, fail to return the desired output.

Comment: @RafiSarker: then this is the third code fragment (with `TruncMinute`).

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.models.function' `

Why doesn't my code just works!!!!
What wrong with this line?


`latest = balance_sheet.objects.filter(timestump__icontains=latest_date)`

Comment: @RafiSarker: `__icontains` works on strings. It would thus look if there is a datetime that is the contains `latest_date`, but that would thus only return exact matches. It would also be completely unscalable since it takes linear time in both the database and the Django/Python layer. The module is `functions` not `function`..